# Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, opencv, ubuntu-20.04, python

I m trying to detect faces using `cascadeClassifier` and `Multiscale` like the code in the example
keeps getting this error
`Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported`

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/prabhat/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

img = cv2.imread("faces.png")

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor = 1.05,
                                     minNeighbors=5)

for x,y,w,h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)

resized = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1]/2),int(img.shape[0]/2)))
cv2.imshow("Gray", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()
```

Comment: i m running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: I am also getting same error